# How to align my world space with Vive Chaperone bounds?

Tags: unity-game-engine, vrtk

I am trying to create a room-scale 1:1 VR experience for HTC Vive using Unity and VRTK.

I have a 3m x 3m tracked space for testing, and in Unity I have created a 3x3 room. However, the walls in my virtual world do not run in parallel with the Play Area chaperone bounds – they are intersecting the chaperone. Have a look at this image:

[image: Chaperone bounds not aligned with room walls]

How do I transform my world space so that it's always in sync with the chaperone bounds?

Comment: Place your headset and controller on center of the virtual room you made

Comment: @MuhammadFaizanKhan I think headset placement is taken care by VRTK when you set up the `VRTK_SDKManager` and select SteamVR in `VRTK_SDKSetup`. I cross-checked all the objects, and all the transforms are set to 0.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the chaperone bounds should always be centered at world space zero coordinate and aligned with the world axis if the *SteamVRController* is in the root of the hierarchy. Are you sure that you are not making it as a child of another object?

You can also check that the dimensions of the tracked area are the one you are expecting by doing something:

```
CVRChaperone chaperoneSystem = OpenVR.Chaperone;
bool success = chaperoneSystem.GetPlayAreaSize(ref m_sizeX,ref m_sizeZ);
```

Comment: I am using VRTK for development, which manages SteamVR SDK for me. I did try getting the play area size using `VRTK_DeviceFinder.PlayAreaTransform()`, which returned the position as `(0, 0, 0)` and rotation as `(0, 0, 0, 1.0)`. So I am not sure what's wrong. Even if I get the correct transform of the chaperone, how do I fix my world space coordinates?